# React how to add class to parent element when child element is clicked

Tags: reactjs

This is my code.

```
export default MainContent = () => {
    handleClick = (e) => {
        // This is where I got confused
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <div onClick={handleClick}>1</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div onClick={handleClick}>2</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div onClick={handleClick}>3</div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

What I want is to **add a class to parent div when child element is clicked**. I couldn't use useState() since I only need one element to update. Couldn't use setAttribute since it changes the same element. Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you want to apply the `class` only to direct `parent` of **clicked** `child`.

- create a `state` to oversee different **clicked** `child` `div`
- apply the `class` only to direct `parent` of *clicked** `child` `div` based on the `state`
- make use of `clsx` `npm package` (since we don't wanna overwrite `parent` `div` styling)
- you may see the working examples here: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-babbage-3eczt

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import styled from "styled-components";
import classnames from "clsx";

export default function App() {
  const [styling, setstyling] = useState({
    status: false,
    from: "",
    style: ""
  });

  function handleClick(childNo) {
    setstyling({ status: true, from: childNo, style: "applyBgColor" });
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Styling>
        <div
          className={
            styling?.status && styling?.from == "child-1"
              ? classnames("indentText", styling?.style)
              : "indentText"
          }
        >
          <div
            className="whenHoverPointer"
            onClick={() => handleClick(`child-1`)}
          >1</div>
        </div>
        <div
          className={
            styling?.status && styling?.from == "child-2" 
              ? styling?.style 
              : ""
          }
        >
          <div
            className="whenHoverPointer"
            onClick={() => handleClick(`child-2`)}
          >2</div>
        </div>
      </Styling>
    </div>
  );
}

const Styling = styled.div`
  .indentText {
    font-style: italic;
  }
  .applyBgColor {
    background-color: grey;
  }
  .whenHoverPointer {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Item({ children }) {
  const [checked, isChecked] = useState(false);
  const onClick = () => isChecked(true);

  return (
    <div {...(isChecked && { className: 'foo' })}>
      <button type="button" onClick={onClick}>{children}</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function MainContent() {
  return [1, 2, 3].map(n => <Item key={n}>{n}</Item>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think theirs something wrong, useState and JSX will update related part, react will handling that itself, but base on logic, may you need to prevent re-render to stop issue, for example, here on handleClick, will keep re-render in each state since function will re-addressed in memory each update..

any way, base on your question, you can do that by this:

```
  const handleClick = useCallback((e) => {
    e.target.parentElement.classList.add('yourClass')
  }, []);
```

But I believe its a **Bad** solution.

What I recommend is solve issue by state to keep your react life cycle is fully work and listen to any update, also you can use ref to your wrapper div and add class by ref.